# Передача параметра has_trailer

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карта-api

Коллеги, добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в api Яндекса есть [параметр](https://yandex.ru/dev/router/doc/ru/request#has_trailer):

- `has_trailer` - Наличие прицепа (только для `mode=truck`). Значение по умолчанию — `false`.*

В их терминологии прицеп - это полуприцеп в том числе? Что этот параметр учитывает? Для нашего бизнеса важно это понимать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Параметр **has_trailer** создан для того, чтобы учитывать зоны действия знака 3.7 «Движение с прицепом запрещено». Знак, как и наш сервис, не проводит различия между прицепами и полуприцепами, поскольку любой вид прицепа у грузового автомобиля запрещает ему движение в зоне действия знака.

Иными словами, этот параметр влияет только на составление таких маршрутов, в которых можно или нельзя проезжать с прицепом или полуприцепом. На другие параметры маршрута (пробег, длительность маршрута) он никак не влияет. Об этом сказано в документации: https://yandex.ru/dev/router/doc/ru/request#mode